# how to call function with parameter in JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to create a listitem click listener with the item as argument in React. But the function itemClick is now called when page is loaded in stead of when I click on a item.

```
itemClick = (item) => {
  console.log(item)
}    

render(){
        return(
            <Fragment>
                {this.state.list.map(item=> (
                   <tr onClick={this.itemClick(item)}>
                    <td>{item.firstname}</td>
                    <td>{item.lastname}</td>
                   </tr>
                ))}
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
```

when I do this the function will be called when i clicked but I can't get the argument

```
<tr onClick={this.itemClick} >
```

Help?

Comment: `onClick={(e) => this.itemClick(item, e)}`or `onClick={this.itemClick.bind(this, item)}`

Comment: This has to do with the binding on "this". See [Handling Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) on React for further information about event handling and [this](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/understanding-javascript-function-prototype-bind/) for further information about binding in functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By writing `this.itemClick(item)` you are invoking `itemClick` directly on render. You can instead create a new inlined function that calls `itemClick` when it is invoked.

```
<tr onClick={() => this.itemClick(item)}>
```